# Servlets birthday calculator tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Can anyone see if there are any errors in this code 
this servlet should be able to send data to the next servlet
i cant compile it myself cause tomcat keeps giving the several ports are in use error even though i restarted tomcat from services and from tomcat/bin was it... i even tried restarting my pc i even tried searching for the 8080 port and closed it ans still the same

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html>");
    out.print("<body>");
    out.println("<form action='end' method='post'>");
    out.println("Month "
            +   "<select>"
            +   "<option mon=1>January</option>"
            +   "<option mon=2>Febuary</option>"
            +   "<option mon=3>March</option>"
            +   "<option mon=4>April</option>"
            +   "<option mon=5>May</option>"
            +   "<option mon=6>June</option>"
            +   "<option mon=7>July</option>"
            +   "<option mon=8>August</option>"
            +   "<option mon=9>October</option>"
            +   "<option mon=10>September</option>"
            +   "<option mon=11>October</option>"
            +   "<option mon=12>Decmeber</option>"
            +   "</select>");
    out.println("Day "
            +   "<select>"
            +   "<option day=1>1</option>"
            +   "<option day=2>2</option>"
            +   "<option day=3>3</option>"
            +   "<option day=4>4</option>"
            +   "<option day=5>5</option>"
            +   "<option day=6>6</option>"
            +   "<option day=7>7</option>"
            +   "<option day=8>8</option>"
            +   "<option day=9>9</option>"
            +   "<option day=10>10</option>"
            +   "<option day=11>11</option>"
            +   "<option day=12>12</option>"
            +   "<option day=13>13</option>"
            +   "<option day=14>14</option>"
            +   "<option day=15>15</option>"
            +   "<option day=16>16</option>"
            +   "<option day=17>17</option>"
            +   "<option day=18>18</option>"
            +   "<option day=19>19</option>"
            +   "<option day=20>20</option>"
            +   "<option day=21>21</option>"
            +   "<option day=22>22</option>"
            +   "<option day=23>23</option>"
            +   "<option day=24>24</option>"
            +   "<option day=25>26</option>"
            +   "<option day=27>27</option>"
            +   "<option day=28>28</option>"
            +   "<option day=29>29</option>"
            +   "<option day=30>30</option>"
            +   "<option day=31>31</option>"
            +   "</select>");
    out.println("Year "
            +"<select>"
            +   "<option yr=1996>1996</option>"
            +   "<option yr=1997>1997</option>"
            +   "<option yr=1998>1998</option>"
            +   "<option yr=1999>1999</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2000>2000</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2001>2001</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2002>2002</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2003>2003</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2004>2004</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2005>2005</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2006>2006</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2007>2007</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2008>2008</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2009>2009</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2010>2010</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2011>2011</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2012>2012</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2013>2013</option>"
            +   "<option yr=2014>2014</option>"
            +   "</select>");
    out.println("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");  
    out.println("</form>");  
    out.print("</body>");
    out.print("</html>");}
```

will send to this servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int bdaymon=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mon"));
    int bdayday=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("day"));
    int bdayyr=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("yr"));
    int fxmon=4;
    int fxday=23;
    int fxyr=2015;
    int calcmon= 0;
    int calcday= 0;
    int calcyr = 0;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html>");
    out.print("<body>");
    if(bdaymon>fxmon){
        calcyr=fxyr-bdayyr-1;
        calcmon=(12-bdaymon)+(fxmon)-1;
        if(bdayday<fxday)
            calcday=fxday-bdayday;
        else if(bdayday>fxday)
            calcmon--;
        else
            calcmon=0;}
    if(bdaymon<fxmon){
        calcyr=fxyr-bdayyr;
        calcmon=fxmon-bdaymon;
        if(bdayday<fxday)
            calcday=fxday-bdayday;
        else if(bdayday>fxday)
            calcmon--;
        else
            calcmon=0;}
    if(bdaymon==fxmon){
        calcyr=fxyr-bdayyr-1;
        calcmon=(12-bdaymon)+(fxmon)-1;
        if(bdayday<fxday)
            calcday=fxday-bdayday;
        else if(bdayday>fxday)
            calcmon--;
        else
            calcmon=0;}
    out.print("You are " + calcyr + "years" + calcmon + "months" + calcday + "days");
    out.print("</body");
    out.print("</html>");
}
```

}

the question is will it run or not if not why?
please dont criticize the way i code our college prof is so slow and dosent really know what she is doing and besides pretty much sleepy when i coded this so yeah flawed logic

Comment: Can you check the default port used by Tomcat app ? You could checked the default port on file `server.xml`. So, I suggest to you change the line `<Connector port="8080" ` for other available port.

Comment: still nothing any other solutions?... hmmm wait will this run?... anyways should i open server.xml from eclipse or notepad?...

Comment: You can open the `server.xml` either from eclipse or notepad. In my opinion, use the notepad because it is a configuration file from Tomcat application server.

Comment: this tomcat makes me cry so much i changed ports i did everything i know and still the same freaking error can i just ask if the code will run or not when i deploy it as a war file or not?...  >.>

Comment: Yes, it's run fine. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

The code provide run fine.  I'm running this code with:

- Eclipse Luna
- Tomcat 7
- Dynamic web application server (version 2.5)

As mentioned to fix this error you can change tomcat port configuration. See details available on [How to change Tomcat default port](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/)